# How to reconstruct files transferred using uTP?

Tags: bittorrent, utorrent

I have read from an article that bit torrent uses uTorrent Transport Protocol.Also as far as I understood, if I am downloading a file using bit torrent, the different pieces can come from different peers. All these packets have the same connection-id. But how can I understand the order in which these packets arrived?

For an e.g., Let P1,P2 and P3 be the peers from which I can get my file. D1 be my system. Then first portion of the file came from P2, second from P1 and third from P3. Is there any way to find which part came from from which system so that I can reconstruct the file from the captured packets?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the individual uTP packets doesn't matter. The uTP protocol takes care of reconstructing the order of the transported stream.

It's not necessary to know from which system torrent 'piece' messages originate to reconstruct a file. By utilizing the data in the metainfo for a torrent, and 'piece' messages per the bittorrent peer protocol it's possible to create the intended files within a torrent.

To avoid confusion, I think you will benefit from knowing that uTP is a level of abstraction *below* the peer protocol in use with each peer.

Comment: So BitTorrent protocol is used to request and receive 'piece', I think. Then what is the need of uTP?

Comment: The protocol only describes the sequences of bytes used in sending and receiving messages. uTP describes how to transmit sequences of bytes over UDP.